# including additinal library paths with #ifdef in c++ visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, include

i have 32bit and 64bit runtime libraries installed in different locations. the library files are named the same. now to make a 32bit application i need to specify the 32bit library path and similar thing for the 64bit. Is there a way to do something like

```
  #ifdef defined (_WIN64)
    include 64bit library path
  #else
    include 32bit library path
  #endif
```

now "#ifdef defined (_WIN64)" for windows platform (i have empirically checked that). And from my simple investigation i learnt that this may not be the best way to determine whether target application is 64bit or 32bit but the issue is not that over here. I want know if there is a way to have similar conditional statements to appropriately include the library paths. I am developing in windows using c++ visual studio 2010. Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest including the _bitness_ in the name of the _lib_. This permits the libaries to live in the same directory and can be moved out of their directory and still retain the information.

Comment: i cannot change the library name. the libraries are 3rd party library and they reside in the two different directories with the same name. the libraries that i am creating has bitness attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with the comment to change the library name, but to answer the question: Use [`#pragma comment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) to specify [`/LIBPATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx):

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/LIBPATH:c:\\test\\")
```

Note that if you change the library name, you could do this instead:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib64.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib32.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: the library path has some space. Is there a way to handle it ? The library path is as follows : c:\Program Files\. how do i handle the space ?

Comment: I would recommend you use a relative path and copy the library somewhere where you don't need spaces. If that is not possible, put quotes around it or use the MSDOS 8.3 short name.